# android google ads footer

Tags: android, ads

i want to integrate googles ads to my application.
the one that you see at the bottom of the screen on most free apps.

but i could not find any website related to that topic. is it related to google adsense?

thanks for any links and guides on how to set it up in the layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [admob](http://www.admob.com/)

Comment: not to "hijack" this, but do you know of a good admob example? I have been trying everything the past couple days and can not get the ads to show, even in test mode. My AdListener calls onFailedToReceiveAd every time. i have followed the dev wiki to the letter :)

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't added ads to any of my apps, yet... Apart from the wiki (http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android) I can't offer any advice.

Comment: :) ok thanks. Either way, I do agree that admob is the best bet, especially since they are owned by google and will eventually be part of adsense anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can check at :
http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/mobile/ads/docs/android/